# Query retorna subclasses no Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, herança

Estou com problemas no mapeamento de classes de um projeto em spring que estou desenvolvendo. Tenho a super classe chamada de ItemPauta e a subclasse Homologação.

> Classe Pai

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="item_pauta")
@AttributeOverrides({
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="ite_id"))
})
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorValue("itemPauta")
public class ItemPauta extends BaseEntity {

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                mappedBy = "itens",targetEntity = Objeto.class)
    List<Objeto> objetos;


//outros campos aqui 


}
```

> classe filha :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="homologacao")
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="hom_id"))
})
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
public class Homologacao extends ItemPauta {

@Column(name="hom_tds")
@Size(max=20)
String numeroTDS;
```

}

Nessa configuração o sistema cria duas tabelas e quando pesquiso na classe pai retorna tmb registros da classe filha. Já tentei com o Inhereted.Joined, mas retornou tmb os registros da classe filha, na classe filha coloquei a anotação explicit e tmb discriminatorValue, mas tmb não obtive resultado.

> Aqui a chamada para a query :

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<ItemPauta> findaAll() {
    return repository.encontrarTodos();
}
```

> classe ItemPautaRepository

```
@Query("select itens from ItemPauta itens")
 public List<ItemPauta> encontrarTodos () ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Vai na sua classe domain e coloca a anotação @JsonIgnore no atributo que você não queira que retorne quando você realizar a pesquisa. Se não funcionar em vez de colocar no atributo coloque no método get, por exemplo:

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getNome(){
    return this.nome;
}
```

Importa do pacote:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
```

Comment: Olá Fábio, agora que li sua resposta obrigado. Eu até desisti de fazer desse jeito, eu resolvi fazer mais uma classe filha e a partir dela fazer a pesquisa: assim o será nas outras subclasses, não irei pesquisar mais na classe pai. Obrigado mesmo assim, vou tentar o que vc me sugeriu.